# How can I make a view of a Controller as Default page in ASP.Net core 2.1 Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

In ASP.NET web application framework, in the case of Web API , I can make the default page of the website by changing the following code:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

of the App_Start Folder's RouteConfig.cs.
But in ASP.Net Core 2.1 application framework's Web API, how can I make a view of a MVC controller as Default Page ? There is no file called RouteConfig.cs

Comment: Why are you wanting view in Web API? Does Web API Controller Methods return view? No! Web API Controller Methods return only status or data.

Comment: @TanvirArjel is there really any difference between Web API and Web App except for projects folder structure generated by VS?

Answer (score 0):

It's configured in Startup.cs in `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ....
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            template: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 1 });                    
    });
}
```